# Credential in SharePoint Site while opening each document

Tags: credentials

Once I log in using the credentials in sharepoint I need to do this for each document I try to open.

So click on a link to some document in SharePoint, input the credentials and it works fine 
but if I then try to open another document the same Windows Security window pops up.
I enter the credentials again the document opens but if I open another........................etc etc 
you get the picture I think.

I would like to know how can i get out of it without using the credential again and again.

Appreciate your response at the earliest.

Thanks

Regards,
Shiny Joseph

Answer (score 0):

You can set the credentials in Windows Credential Manager and then ensure that the SharePoint site is in the Local Intranet zone. You should then avoid prompts.

Comment: Thanks for the response Steve. Windows credential Manager was already set. We never faced this kind of issue before. Not sure why all of a sudden it started. Any Idea ?

Comment: We see it when the site is not in Local Intranet Zone, as I say. I've also seen the prompt even with both credential manager and local intranet configured but only sometimes, not every document. MS Office seems a bit random in when and how often it prompts for credentials.